# R: Viewing multiple objects using View function

Tags: r, object

I have 10 objects eg1, eg2, eg3....eg10 that I want to see using the View() function in R. I have a feeling that I can write a simple code that would run View(egi) with i from 1 to 10, but I'm not sure how I could write this in R. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: See [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) for why it's better to store them in a list

Comment: @DavidRobinson That's a little over my head, as a nonprogrammer. I get that `a.append` suggests the existence of `a`, etc., but I guess most R users wouldn't. I don't know a better ref, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest `Map`, like this:

```
eg1 <- eg2 <- eg3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
egs <- mget(ls(pattern = "^eg"))
Map(View, egs, names(egs))
```

Wrap it in `invisible` before running it if you don't want all those pesky `NULL`s in your console.

Proof :-)

[image]

Comment: Seems to be simple loop-hiding, but I like it. `mapply` does the same.

Comment: @Frank, simple pleasures :-) `soanswer` from the "overflow" package doesn't handle non-console answers, so I had to resort to other trickery to keep myself entertained.

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed that package of yours before. Neat stuff

Answer (score 6):

Keep your stuff in a list

```
egs <- mget(ls(pattern="^eg"))
```

and loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(egs)) View(egs[[i]],title=names(egs)[i])
```

Comment: Thank you! Probably trivial, but do you think I could potentially have the windows' titles be eg1, eg2...etc?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a silly example, first put all your object in a list:

```
 my.list<-list(data.frame(V1=1:10),data.frame(V1=11:20),data.frame(V1=21:30) )
```

then do

```
  lapply(my.list,View)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
names <- paste0("eg",seq(1:10))
sapply(1:1O, function(x) View(eval(parse(text=names[x]))))
```